# Multiple TFS "hosts" behind a simple iis loadballancer

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, load-balancing, team-foundation-server

I got a simple setup for a way to distribute loads for my websites using (at the moment) 3 IIS servers and Application Request Routing.

I'm wondering, does TFS handle being installed on the 2 backends well or might it cause some issues when eg. committing changesets from visual studio?

The plan is to have an "outside url" tfs.foo.local that points to the first iis that forwards the requests 50/50 to the backend iis servers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It [doesn't look like](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/tfsgeneral/thread/212b3821-4464-4ea6-aa85-01e0cae6e496) Team Foundation Server 2008 supports application-level load balancing.

Apparently [2010 does, though?](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee259689.aspx)

Comment: Thanks that's what I was looking for, off to the planning board for me then :)

Comment: Any reason why you are still using TFS2008? TFS2010 is an enormous improvement. It supports 64-bit, load balancing and is faster.

Comment: @GrantHolliday I'm using TFS 2010, I didn't specify it in the original  post, so Matt Simmons covered both scenarios :) (should be able to vote up twice, since he did formulate the answer well and covered both ways)